# Both `name="button"` and `name="submit" work properly in the form

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

When working in Django,

Both `name="button"` and `name="submit"` work properly when I submit the form

```
    {% buttons %}
        <button name="button" class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
    {% endbuttons%}
    {% buttons %}
        <button name="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
    {% endbuttons%}
```

What's the difference between `button` and `submit`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Comment: my question is not about type. @ThiagoMata

Comment: Do you have Javascript in your form? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Use `google chrome` and import `bootstrap3` @Lex don't have Js in my form.

Comment: According to MDN [type button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) has no default behaviour . I could be the browser still interprets the button as a submit action; Or there is js adding a submit action on the button

Comment: Yeah the browser assumes its Submit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403415/google-chrome-submits-form-even-if-there-is-no-submit-button

Comment: amazing, I am unable to upvote your comments with 3 reputations, could you please transmit your comments to the answer. @Lex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" />
```

buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default, this is usually used along with JS to make some form of request or call a function.

```
<input type="submit">
```

this will submit the form that the input is within when it is clicked by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `type` attribute, ie: `type="button"` and `type="submit"`, rather than the `name` attribute.